# How to test notification implemented using signal r

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have used Signal R to implement face book kind of notification in MVC 4 application. by referring

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/sending-notifications-using-asp.net-signalr.htm

With the generated proxy code.
I have the **notification count bubble**(span) in the lay out page and there is another Add notification page where i have a text box and button . On click of button i am calling a hub method to broadcast the message.there i am sending notification to all the client using 
client.all.briadcastnotification()

I have 2 pages opened. one home page and the add notification page where i have typed a message to broadcast.When i clicked on send button notification count bubble(span) got updated on the add notification page. But in the other page ((Home page) the notification count bubble(span) is not getting updated. Does it need to update all the pages ??

Also please help me how i can test whether the notification message is sending to ALL THE CLIENTS .I am new to signal R and MVC and stackoverflow as well.

Comment: Can some gives me idea on how to test

Comment: may be you can try different browsers, or ask other developers to run app at same time you do

Comment: here my send and recieve code is in the same page where admin will send messages. And my notification count is in the main menu layout. But the notifiation count is not getting updated in the main menu. Any idea how it can be updated on the main layout. Practically menu will be loaded only once.